# Grouped Barplot Python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

i need help, I tried do make grouped barplots. 
But it doesn't work. 
At first I read in all tab folders and than I want so get 2 columns ('special name' and 'ab') for the x-axes. 
In 'special name' are only 3 different kind of names, but all of them have 4 or 7 'ab' which belong to them.

```
Example tab file
Names  names_id  first second special_name   ab
lili      1         a      b    Tm           a
Katrin    2         c      d    Tm           u
Paul      3         e      f    ui           f
bob       4         g      h    ui           b
tina      5         i      j    ac           a
```

And the y-axes should tell me the numbers how often each 'ab' was count.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import os
import glob
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import ggplot
from ggplot import aes

sns.set(style= "whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True )

tab_folder = 'myData'
out_folder ='myData/plots'
tab = glob.glob('%s/R*.tab'%(tab_folder))

#is reading all my data
for i, tab_file in enumerate(tab):
    folder,file_name=os.path.split(tab_file)
    s_id=file_name[:-4].replace('DD','')
    df=pd.DataFrame.from_csv(tab_file, sep='\t')
    df_2 = df.groupby(['special_name','ab']).size().reset_index(name='count')

    #Here I wanted to create grouped barplots
    ggplot(df_2, aes(x=('special_name'), y=('count'), fill=('ab'))) + geom_bar(stat='identity',position='dodge')

    ax.set_title(s_id)
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    ax.set_ylabel('')

png_t = '%s/%s.b.png'%(out_folder,s_id)
plt.savefig(png_t, dpi = 500)
```

My code doesn't give an error anymore. But I only get empty grids.... What's wrong?

When I try ggplot.ggplot():

```
AttributeError:                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-03dc98f5428a> in <module>()
    100 
    101     #barplots 
--> 102     ggplot.ggplot(df_2, aes(x=('special_name'), y=('count'), fill=('ab'))) + geom_bar(stat='identity',position='dodge')
```

AttributeError: type object 'ggplot' has no attribute 'ggplot'

Comment: I'm guessing you need something like `ggplot.ggplot()`, you are trying to call the module itself.

Comment: I tried ggplot.ggplot() but it wasn't working.   I think I know what you mean, but I don't know any other variant.

Comment: When reporting about an error, we need a [mcve] of the issue and the full error traceback (not just the last line of it). MartinEvans comment above is absolutely correct and as it currently stands the only hint one can give.

Comment: I'm sorry. Now there's the whole error at the end of my code

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake!
I don't need ggplot. I only had to modify my df_2

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import os
import glob
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import ggplot
from ggplot import aes

sns.set(style= "whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True )

tab_folder = 'myData'
out_folder ='myData/plots'
tab = glob.glob('%s/R*.tab'%(tab_folder))

#is reading all my data
for i, tab_file in enumerate(tab):
    folder,file_name=os.path.split(tab_file)
    s_id=file_name[:-4].replace('DD','')
    df=pd.DataFrame.from_csv(tab_file, sep='\t')


    #Here I create grouped barplots
    df_2 = df.groupby(['special_name','ab']).size().reset_index(name='count')
    table = pd.pivot_table(df_2, index='special_name', columns='ab', values='count')
    table.plot(kind='barh', color= ['r', 'g', 'b', 'k', 'm', 'y'], ax = ax)

    ax.set_title(s_id)
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    ax.set_ylabel('')

png_t = '%s/%s.b.png'%(out_folder,s_id)
plt.savefig(png_t, dpi = 500)
```